# Vuforia vs Metaio vs Layar

Tags: vuforia, metaio, layar

I am new to markerless AR. I have done one Marker based AR application. As I want to develop applications based on Markerless AR and considering the fact that I am new to markerless AR, I want to know the advantages and disadvantages for the following SDKs: Vuforia, Metaio, and Layar to start developing markerless AR applications.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based. Although, people have answered a similar question in the past. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227962/qualcomms-vuforia-qcar-vs-metaio-sdk-vs-dfusion-mobile-vs-layar-sdk/13034146#13034146

Answer (score -1):

Both Vuforia and Metaio provide resources for developers.
Both platforms are pretty equal in 2D image tracking with Unity.

The difference comes with 3D tracking. Metaio seems to be the leader in this now with their various types- Edge based, point cloud, etc.

I'd say stick to Vuforia unless you absolutely need the 3D tracking.

the text above is answers of people in unity forums
for more detail -> http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/vuforia-vs-metaio.230838/