# Walking around an AR Object in Unity for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I have seen some amazing examples of stuff that can be made using ARKit for iPhone, but are there any Android alternatives that can run on Unity?

For an AR app I'm trying to place a virtual object on the scene and allow the user to walk around the object as if it where real using just the cellphone like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIPfpGCxONQ):

How can this be done for Android?

Regards!

Comment: Have you read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227962/vuforia-vs-metaio-sdk-vs-arkit-vs-dfusion-mobile-vs-layar-sdk?rq=1

Comment: Nope.. I'm reading them right now... but i do have used vuforia for some projects